# Wireless Accessory Configuration alternative on android platform?

Tags: android, wifi, wireless

I was wondering if there was anybody which have any information regarding alternatives on Wireless Accessory Configuration on the Android platform.

I know TI has a solution called simpleconfig, but I was wondering if there was any "generic" method which is not linked to a specific chip manufacture?

Is the Android platform limited to having a long and difficult configuration sequence when getting wifi accessories on the network?

Comment: Any luck finding out more info on this?

Comment: I am looking for same if anybody get any clue for generic WAC mechanism for Android, please post here.

Comment: Anyone here find any information?

Comment: As far as I have been able to find, there is no system level solution in android that give the same ease of use as WAC. We are currently looking into developing our own solution on android to simulate WAC as good as possible on the Android platform, but since the solution, is not on system level we will not be able to make it as user friendly as WAC.